# How can a Google crawlers see PHP dynamic content?

Tags: php, google

I'm reading the Google SEO starter guide and on page 11 it says you should prepare a site for users and one for search engines in XML.

My site is about vehicles, and vehicle is not in a separate folder. It gets loaded dynamically with GET and PHP – so can Google crawl this if it's "not really there"?

The pages are there under `?GET` variables like `home.com/seevehicles?2009-camar` so am I doing it wrong or can Google also crawl this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic content is "dynamic" only server-side, clients always get just plain HTML (in other words: everything is static when it reaches client). It doesn't matter for a browser (or a crawler) if the document was dynamic or static, it's all the same: just a bunch of tags that it has to interpret.

If a regular visitor can see a link (or a hyperlink, if you prefer that name), it means that his browser has found a `<a>` tag and interpreted it as a link. If a browser could do that, then crawler can do that too. So, a crawler has an URL, it will follow it and do its job again: index it and follow next links. It doesn't magically enumerate server files and hit them one by one, it's only following links.

Answer (score 0):

Just make hyperlinks using hard coded links to the homepage. Job done. It can crawl any HREF.

Once you have these links, [build a sitemap.xml](http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/) and link to it in [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en).

Comment: what do you mean? can you please explain to me more of this, hyperlinks? but if i make a link to that 2009 car, the day of tomorrow it might not be there, are you saying i should spit this xml with php aswell? damn im confused